# Android BufferedReader try-with-resources

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

Hopefully I can clearly ask my question this time, I embarrassed myself with my last question so I had to delete it.

This snippet is from a logger I am writing for my app.  When I wrote this in Eclipse Luna, I was given no errors on the try() statement I made below, but when I plug the code into Android Studio, I am given an "Incompatible types" error.  It states that the type found was "java.io.BufferedReader", and expected is "java.lang.AutoCloseable".  What am I missing?

```
File filePointer = new File(logFile);
    boolean bool = false;
    bool = filePointer.exists();
    String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    if(bool == true) {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(logFile))) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while(line != null){
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(ls);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            copiedFile = sb.toString();
        }
        finally{
            br.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It might be giving you the wrong error.  It's possible that you need to update your JRE compilation to support at least JRE 1.7

Comment: My "Source Compatibility" is set to 1.7.  Also, the JDK I'm using is 1.8.0.  Relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your minimum API level.  The `java.lang.AutoCloseable` interface wasn't added to Android until API 19.  So the Java 7 'try-with-resources' feature isn't available unless you are building with Java 7 *and* your `minSdkVersion` is set to 19.

Comment: Errors seem to have gone away! Thanks for that. I am new to Java, Android, and programming in general. I have been tasked with developing a basic application for our company and am slowly learning all aspects.

Comment: Is there another class to replace BufferedReader in previous versions of Android 19?

Comment: `BufferedReader` has been in the framework since API 1, it's not new.  The new thing in this post was the *try-with-resources* feature (e.g. the statement after the `try` keyword which creates the `BufferedReader`.)